# Display title of selected subpage on top of drop down menu (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a drop down menu on a page that I'm building for a client (using Wordpress). The title of the drop down is "Menu" and it doesn't link anywhere, it just displays the drop down menu-items on hover.

When you select a subpage, is there a way to display the title of the active page where it says "Menu" on the startpage? For example, on Page 1 it would say Page 1 instead of Menu.

I have looked around for options, but haven't found anything satisfying so far.

The code for the menu:

```
<nav class="x-nav-wrap desktop" role="navigation">
    <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="x-nav">
        <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-36"> <a href="#">
    <span>MENU</span></a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-37 current_page_item menu-item-42"> <a href="http://test.frankochrakel.se/?page_id=37"><span>Page 1</span></a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41"> <a href="http://test.frankochrakel.se/?page_id=39"><span>Page 2</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

http://test.frankochrakel.se/

I'm grateful for any ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Why not have your `page_id=37` number target the page number? Example Page 1 - page_id=1? You could use .htaccess to display as `www.yourdomain.com/page1/` and that will target `www.yourdomain.com/?page_id=1`. Then you can setup javascript to check the domain for index of `/page` and set that into the menu replacing menu?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this jquery in your `header.php` file.

#### Jquery in header.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var get_current_menu_item = $('.sub-menu .current-menu-item span').text();
    if(get_current_menu_item)
        $('#menu-item-36 > a span').text(get_current_menu_item);
});
```

*If this is not working, replace '$' with 'jQuery' and try again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79116/discussion-on-answer-by-yeyene-display-title-of-selected-subpage-on-top-of-drop).